# Page Mapping Layout

Tags: linux, paging, memory-mapping

I am confused about the 4-level page layout in X86-64 architectures. In the Linux source code implementation, they use: 
**PGD(Page Global Directory) --> PUD(Page Upper Directory) --> PMD(Page Medium Directory) --> PTE**

However, I also found another four-level page layout fro X86 architecture:
**PML4(L4) --> PDP(L3) --> PD(L2) --> PTE(L1)**

So, is there anyone knows the difference between these two page layouts? May I consider the PML4 as the same component as PGD? If so the CR3 (PDBR) actually contains the address for PGD right?

A detailed answer will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you found both sets of names (exact links if possible)? Possibly linux just uses alternative or bit architecture-neutral variants of names.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have figured out my confusions (Described in the answer).

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question here:

Multi-level page table structures are pretty common in the modern architectures.
General term to describe the 4-level paging layout is: **PGD-PUD-PMD-PTE**, which is a widely used general terminology. Linux system source code actually also uses these terms to define the paging structures.

However, Intel uses its own terminology: **PML4(L4) - PDP(L3) - PD(L2) - PTE(L1)**.

The ideas between these two are the same!